# Show map extent as a polygon onto another map - OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

How can one add a polygon that represents at all time the extent of map1 onto map2 as in the following page?

[image]
http://www.alexisathlani.com/paris.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The function that creates the polygon

```
function addExtent(){
    // Remove the previous polygon
    extentSource.clear();
    // Get the extent of the map and store it in an array of coordinates 
    var extentMap = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
    var bottomLeft = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getBottomLeft(extentMap),
      'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var topRight = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getTopRight(extentMap),
      'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var bottomRight = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getBottomRight(extentMap),
      'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var topLeft  = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getTopLeft(extentMap),
      'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
    var ring = [ 
        [bottomLeft[0], bottomLeft[1]], 
        [topLeft[0], topLeft[1]] , 
        [topRight[0], topRight[1]],
        [bottomRight[0], bottomRight[1]]
    ];
   // Create a polygon based on the array of coordinates
   var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([ring]);
   polygon.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
   // Add the polygon to the layer and style it
   var feature = new ol.Feature(polygon);
   extentSource.addFeature(feature);
   feature.setStyle(extentStyle);
}
```

### The polygon style / Layer Variables / Views and Maps

```
var extentStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'white',
        width: 1.5
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
    })
});

var extentSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var extentLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    source: extentSource,
});
var basemap = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.XYZ({ url: 'http://{1-4}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',}),});

var center = ol.proj.transform([2.360122, 48.924520], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
var center2 = ol.proj.transform([2.359399, 48.897674], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 

var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 16,
});
var view2 = new ol.View({
    center: center2,
    zoom: 12.15,
});

var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [basemap],
        view: view,
});
var map2 = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map2',
        layers: [basemap, extentLayer],
        view: view2,
});
```

### The listeners that tell OL when to update the polygon

```
// The listeners you need really depends on your project. These 3 were enough for mine.

// Initialize the polygon when the page is first loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    addExtent();
});
// Change the polygon whenever the map is moved
map.on('move', function(){
    addExtent();
});
// Change the polygon whenever the map is clicked
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    addExtent();
});
```